# How to add user defined methods in C# TBB(C# code fragment)?

Tags: c#, tridion

I am creating a C# TBB(C# Code fragment). For that I need to write a userdefined method. I tried creating it using <%! %>. How to access the user defined method in the code. Thanks in advance. Please suggest me a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The TOM.NET API reference provides the following example:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing"%>
<%!
private string ExtraString()
{
    return "Something added by the C# template";
}
%>
log.Debug("Executing C# template");
if (engine.RenderMode == RenderMode.Publish)
{
    package.GetByName(Package.OutputName).AppendToStringValue(ExtraString());
}
```

In addition to the above, the following syntax is supported:

```
<%@Import Namespace="..." %>
```

Imports the namespace enclosed between the quotation marks into the code fragment. Any class you import must be present in the Global Assembly Cache.

```
<%! ... %>
```

Declares methods, constants and classes for the rest of the code fragment to use. The declarations cannot contain the string '%>'. Note that any classes you create can only be referenced within the code fragment.

```
<%RunTemplate Template="tcm:1-184-2048" Class="Tridion.Templating.Examples.ExampleTemplateClass"%>
```

Runs a specific .NET Assembly Template Building Block, identified by the URI in the Template attribute. This statement is typically generated by SDL Tridion 2009 itself when you upload a .NET assembly, to provide access to a specific class in the .NET Assembly.

```
<%@Assembly Name="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"%>
```

Inserts a reference to a nonstandard .NET assembly, which must be present in the Global Assembly Cache. Use the full assembly name.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the documentation page where you got this from?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation [reference link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=c%2523%2520fragment&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1336480377584&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_A09C15BAC797438B85765FF06730CF12&query=&scope=&filename=CSharpFragmentScriptingSyntax.xml&docid=concept_A09C15BAC797438B85765FF06730CF12&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=) with example that Nickol pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Check these below links for complete details on creating Functions as well as Classes in a C# Code Fragment.

1. Functions: 
   https://rcnitesh.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/functions-in-c-tbb/
   **[For full details including code samples, check the above link ]**
2. Classes: 
   https://rcnitesh.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/creating-user-defined-classes-in-c-code-fragment/ 
   Below is an excerpt from the above Blog:

Classes are defined inside a C# Code Fragment  using the construct: `<%! %>`.

This USER defined class is placed as NESTED CLASS of the PREDEFINED CLASS created by Tridion when compiling the C# Code fragment. Check this blog post for in depth details on C# Code Fragment compilation and the Predefined classes , methods generated by tridion together with understanding the relation of  Tridion’s Predefined class with User defined Class in a C# Code Fragment

That said above, what we need to understand is that the User defined classes in a C# Code Fragment cannot access the predefined variables like: log, engine,  and package , since these variables are actually declared Private in the Predefined class  generated during compilation.

**[For full details including code samples, check the above links ]**