# SDL Tridion C# code fragment can't find engine, package or log fields in context

Tags: c#, tridion

I'm quite new to Tridion development and I'm having my first "basic" issue.
I've written a simple C# code fragment in a TBB (using content manager text editor) and I've tried to use engine, package and log fields (as I know they are made available by Tridion) but  I receive an error saying "the name does not exist in context".
Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
<div>
        <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.crociera" -->
              <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="prezzo<250" -->
                     Go to @@location@@<br/>
              <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
        <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
</div>
<%
String ts = DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMM yyyy");
Response.Write("<br/>"+ts);
engine.getSession();
%>
```

When I save the TBB and publish the page I receive this error:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'engine' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 31: Response.Write("<br/>"+ts);
Line 32: engine.getSession();
Line 33: %>                         
Line 34:                  </div>

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\stage\pj\ricerca\ricerca.aspx    Line: 32
```

Probably I miss something or do something wrong, does anyone recognize the problem?

Comment: Have you created a DWT template or a C# fragment? You've got syntax from both mixed up together. It's not working because you've mixed two things that are not compatible in this manner.

Comment: From the `Source File` marker at the bottom of the error message, it seems that this is not a TBB - but a ASPX page in the web site.

Comment: I've created a DWT template but all the C# works fine except for the "engine.getSession()" statement. Do I have to declare it as a C# code fragment and remove all the HTML and DWT scripting code?

Comment: Sounds like you've added the code to DWT so that it gets published to an ASPX file. Is that correct? If so then you're doing it wrong. Templating code is not executed on your website, but by the rendering engine within SDL Tridion.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the aspx is the page in which the TBB is executed.

Comment: TBBs don't run in ASPX pages...

Comment: Ok @JeremyGrand-Scrutton I presume that's my error, I'll try to create a new C# code fragment with my engine "manipulation" and add it to the page in the template builder is that correct? The page should still be aspx or what?

Comment: The file extension of the Page Template used is irrelevant. The code in your C# fragment is executed in the context of the template (CT or PT) by the Tridion rendering engine, before the published output reaches the target web server.

Your C# code may even be correct (as long as it's not the fragment you posted above).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Engine` object you use is part of Tridion's TOM.NET API, which is only available to your code while the item is being published.

Once the ASPX page reaches the front-end server, the TOM.NET API is not available anymore. Part of the reason for this is that the Tridion Content Manager is simply not reachable from your web server anymore.

Instead of programming against the Tridion Content Manager through its TOM.NET API, you need to program against Tridion Content Delivery through its API. You can find the documentation for common cases in the [Live Docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_C72D061178C64B88A93134DE051A082C) (log in required).

Answer (score 3):

You can find information on how to properly create a C# fragment at [How to add user defined methods in C# TBB(C# code fragment)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477483/how-to-add-user-defined-methods-in-c-sharp-tbbc-code-fragment)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I've read the sdllivecontent "C# fragment scripting syntax" section but even if I copy/paste code in my TBB I receive the same compile time error.